# Multiple relations to same class in Loopback

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I am trying to understand how relations work in Loopback. Assume that there is a game model and for a game, there are two teams (home and away). Here is how I defined those:

```
{
  "name": "Game",
  "plural": "games",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "gameId": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true,
      "id": true
    },
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "homeTeam": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Team",
      "foreignKey": ""
    },
    "awayTeam": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Team",
      "foreignKey": ""
    },
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

So home team and away team belongs to a team object each. Here's my team model:

```
{
  "name": "Team",
  "plural": "teams",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "teamId": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true,
      "id": true
    },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "games": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Game",
      "foreignKey": "teamId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

So a team can have many games. This sounds correct to me. When I go to `http://localhost:3000/api/games/1871811/homeTeam` it shows me the home team in that game correctly. Same for the away team. But when I go to `http://localhost:3000/api/teams/53/games`, it only responds with `[]`. I am pretty sure that ids are correct.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: On Game model, I think you need to have properties of homeTeam ids and away team ids so that you can do mapping those two different models

Answer (score 0):

on games, you don't need to set property for its id. loopback will automatically create auto-increment id. games table should hold awayTeamId and homeTeamId so that you can do mapping to get data from home to away or away to home.
but also those ids will be created by loopback when you set it on relations foreignkey

#### games.model

```
{
  "name": "games",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {

  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "homeTeam": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "homeTeam",
      "foreignKey": "homeTeamId",
      "options": {
        "disableInclude": false
      }
    },
    "awayTeam": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "awayTeam",
      "foreignKey": "awayTeamId",
      "options": {
        "disableInclude": false
      }
    }

  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

#### away, home model

```
{
    "name": "awayTeam",
    "base": "PersistedModel",
    "idInjection": true,
    "options": {
      "validateUpsert": true
    },
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "validations": [],
    "relations": {
      "games": {
        "type": "hasMany",
        "model": "games",
        "foreignKey": "awayTeamId",
        "options": {
          "disableInclude": false
        }
      }
    },
    "acls": [],
    "methods": {}
  }
```

it's the same for home and away models too
no need to set their own ids and it will refer homeTeamId/ awayTeamId by using foreignKey

ps. if you are using in-memory datasource, you need to put data every time when you change code and rerun the server.

Comment: I am including gameId in the model because I want to keep the same id for games with my API provider. So whatever my API call returns, I am assigning that as id for Game model. Do I have to have different models for home and away teams? I mean that could be a solution but I feel like that would give more problems than it solves. I'm not using in-memory datasource, by the way.

Comment: hm.. or maybe it returns [ ] because the id you put to team model is actually primary key id not teamId ? actually it will be easy to use remoteMethod and debug them